# Почему не работает if

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select IF((SELECT `balans` as bal FROM sim) < 300 , bal, 300)
```

Не работает вот такой простой запрос, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сравниваете весь столбец с числом, что неверно.
Я советую вам делать все это ещё в первом `select` (прошу поправить, если синтаксис неверен, работаю с `oracle`):

```
select case when balans < 300 then balans
            else 300 end as bal
from sim
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL допускает под-запрос во фразе SELECT только если он вернёт скаляр, т.е. **одно** значение, это не ваш случай! А главное незачем так усложнять. И почему-то мне кажется, что вы перепутали больше с меньше ;) Попробуйте две функции: LEAST() и GREATEST(), одна из них вам подойдёт:

```
SELECT LEAST(`balans`, 300) as bal 
FROM sim
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest